# Format the output of qDebug for QMaps

Tags: c++, qt, formatting

i am currently in the process of maintaining a legacy app. This has quite a few structures like:

```
QMap<QString, QMap<QString, QMap<QString, QMap<QString, QVariant> > > > Dep;
```

As interfaces are hardly used and I only need to make minor adjustments, I would like to keep the structure as it is, although some refactoring might be needed anyway. 
But to be able to understand what is going on, currently I just put some qDebug() << Dep; in there, and try to understand the output.

Problem is that it has no formatting at all. Does anyone know of a little script to create a better understandable display format? Or maybe of some patches to Qt?

To give you an example for my suffering:

```
QMap(("Test enable|test enable block", QMap(("disabled", QMap(("testblock1", QMap(("enableblock", QVariant(QString, "false") ) )  ) )  ) ( "enabled" ,  QMap(("testblock1", QMap(("enableblock", QVariant(QString, "true") ) )  ) )  ) )  ) ( "Test enable|test enable key" ,  QMap(("disabled", QMap(("testblock1|testkey", QMap(("enablekey", QVariant(QString, "false") ) )  ) )  ) ( "enabled" ,  QMap(("testblock1|testkey", QMap(("enablekey", QVariant(QString, "true") ) )  ) )  ) )  ) ( "testinsertitems|Insert item" ,  QMap(("test1", QMap(("testinsertitems|testinsert", QMap(("insertitems", QVariant(QVariantMap, QMap(("test1", QVariant(QString, "test1") ) )  ) ) )  ) ( "testinsertitems|testremove" ,  QMap(("removeitems", QVariant(QVariantMap, QMap(("test1", QVariant(QString, "test1") ) )  ) ) )  ) )  ) ( "test2" ,  QMap(("testinsertitems|testinsert", QMap(("insertitems", QVariant(QVariantMap, QMap(("test2", QVariant(QString, "test2") ) )  ) ) )  ) ( "testinsertitems|testremove" ,  QMap(("removeitems", QVariant(QVariantMap, QMap(("test2", QVariant(QString, "test2") ) )  ) ) )  ) )  ) )  ) ( "testsetminmax|test setmin" ,  QMap(("2", QMap(("testsetminmax|testkey1", QMap(("setmin", QVariant(int, 2) ) )  ) ( "testsetminmax|testkey2" ,  QMap(("setmax", QVariant(int, 2) ) )  ) )  ) ( "3" ,  QMap(("testsetminmax|testkey1", QMap(("setmin", QVariant(int, 3) ) )  ) ( "testsetminmax|testkey2" ,  QMap(("setmax", QVariant(int, 3) ) )  ) )  ) )  ) ( "testsetvalue|test set value" ,  QMap(("2", QMap(("testsetvalue|testkey1", QMap(("setvalue", QVariant(QString, "2") ) )  ) ( "testsetvalue|testkey2" ,  QMap(("setvalue", QVariant(QString, "2") ) )  ) ( "testsetvalue|testkey3" ,  QMap(("setvalue", QVariant(QString, "2") ) )  ) )  ) ( "3" ,  QMap(("testsetvalue|testkey1", QMap(("setvalue", QVariant(QString, "3") ) )  ) ( "testsetvalue|testkey2" ,  QMap(("setvalue", QVariant(QString, "3") ) )  ) ( "testsetvalue|testkey3" ,  QMap(("setvalue", QVariant(QString, "3") ) )  ) )  ) )  ) )
```

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This one is for n-dimensions and will use the standard qDebug output for known types:

```
template<class NonMap>
struct Print
{
    static void print(const QString& tabs, const NonMap& value) 
    {
        qDebug() << tabs << value;
    }
};

template <class Key, class ValueType >
struct Print<class QMap<Key, ValueType> >
{
    static void print(const QString& tabs, const QMap< Key, ValueType>& map )
    {
        const QString extraTab = tabs + "\t";
        QMapIterator<Key, ValueType> iterator(map);
        while(iterator.hasNext())
        {
            iterator.next();
            qDebug() << tabs << iterator.key(); 
            Print<ValueType>::print(extraTab, iterator.value());
        }
    }
};

template<class Type>
void printMe(const Type& type )
{
    Print<Type>::print("", type);
};
```

Comment: Impressive use of templates and recursion :)

Answer (score 4):

A four dimensional structure is notoriously hard to visualize.
But how about some small loops?

```
typedef QMap<QString, QVariant> T1;
typedef QMap<QString, T1> T2;
typedef QMap<QString, T2> T3;

foreach( T3 i, dep ) {
    cout << "******" << i.key() << "*******" << endl << endl;
    foreach ( T2 j, i.value() ) {
        cout << j.key() << ":" << endl;
        foreach ( T3 k, j.value() ) {
            cout << k.key() << "= ";
            foreach ( QVariant l, k.value() ) {
                cout << l.key() << ": " << l.value() << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Using namespace std, of course. Add in setw() as you like. Hope you get the idea.